# ASP.NET update button not working and no errors are showing

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications

I am developing a web application using asp.net with c#. The update button that I have used on other web pages is not working on this web page. The same code I have changed according to the requirements. But it's not showing errors nor updating. Does anyone know what to do or how to debug?

[Calling for function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b7PwP.png)

[Function that I've created to update the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snEbI.png)

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Please attach your code as snippet instead of images. Thanks.

Comment: [How to debug? Learn from this MS Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/debugger-feature-tour?view=vs-2019)

Comment: does the code even run, and the button fire? You have to provide more context, and at least the markup for the button - and  bit of surrounding markup.  We not mind readers here.